# mysql delete operation

Tags: mysql

is there a way to delete a relation only if it exists in the table?
If not,
Whats the best approach when deleting a relation in a table:

1. Check if the relation exists. If it does then delete. (2 operations)
2. Delete and catch the error if it didnt exist. (1 operation)

Thanks

Comment: Define exactly what you mean by "relation" in this context.  Typically, relations exist "between" tables, not "in" them.

Comment: My definition of relation is a row in a table

Comment: Do you actually *care* if it wasn't there to begin with?

Comment: I ask because in your #2, there is no error.  DELETE FROM table WHERE id = [some id that doesn't exist] is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id=30
```

will delete a row if it exists and will do nothing if it is not. No need for catching errors.

Comment: In summary, there is no need to check if the row exists before trying to delete it.

Comment: Nope, if it doesn't exist, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

DELETE deletes a row only if it's exist. It doesn't throw an error if there is nothing to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a subselect and choose which record you want to delete from that subselect, something like this

```
DELETE FROM target WHERE target_table.id IN (
  SELECT target_table.id INNER JOIN relation_table ON relation_table.target_table_id = target_table.id
)
```

where the subselect, using `INNER JOIN` will return records with relations =)

hope it helps! =)