# Delete data outside of array value

Tags: mysql

I Have a problem. I have a `db_bid_product` table on my database.

its look like;

```
CREATE TABLE db_bid_products (
  Id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  BId int(11) default NULL COMMENT 'Bid Id',
  PId int(11) default NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
  Piece int(11) default '0',
  Discount int(11) default '0',
  Price int(11) default '0',
  Currency int(11) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (Id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin5;
```

When edit this table `PId` value is come form look like;

```
10, 6, 5, 1
```

For example; current value on my database is

```
10, 6, 5, 1
```

New value:

```
10, 6, 5, 2
```

I want to delete PId = 1 and add new PId value 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql delete operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530349/mysql-delete-operation)

Comment: Thanks @khuderm but i sloved problem use `Not In`

Comment: As an aside, why not call the columns bid_id and product_id in the first place?